# Is Java Synchronization required when loading data from another thread once?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an integer in my Statistics.java class like this

```
int completionAmount = 0;
```

When the program startups I run a sql query in the main() method and set the *completionAmount* int based on what it returns (such as 10000).

After that's done I start a new single threaded executor that runs every 1 second and it uses that *completionAmount* integer to keep counting, do I need to synchornize the access to that integer now every time I use it in the new thread, because I loaded it from the main thread on startup, or since the main thread will no longer be using the integer, I won't have to make any changes?

Comment: @StephenC Why? Synchronization is ensured by its logic!

Comment: I think the answer depends on what exactly you are doing. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are doing something like this, in the same thread:

```
completionAmount = /* initialize from query; never set again */

new Thread(/* thing that uses completionAmount */).start();
```

then no, no additional synchronization is needed.

According to [JLS 17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.

So, you've got a happens-before relationship between the write to `completionAmount` and its read.

---

Actually, you mention a single-threaded executor in the question. I'm assuming this is specifically an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). From the Javadoc:

> Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable or Callable task to an ExecutorService happen-before any actions taken by that task, which in turn happen-before the result is retrieved via Future.get().

So, provided the assignment happens before you submit the task to the executor, you've got a happens-before relationship, so no additional synchronization is required.

Answer (score -2):

If "a single-threaded executor" you mention is a single-threaded ExecutorService,then synchronization is not needed.

Beacause single-threaded ExecutorService can ensure only one thread can access *completionAmount* integer on the same time,and the rest of your code must keep that.

**Integer** is not thread safe,you can use **AtomicInteger** instead of **Integer** to ensure thread safe.

Comment: This answer does not explain why the executor's worker thread is guaranteed to see the same value that was stored by the program's main thread. Andy Turner's answer gives the correct explanation.